# satellite view toggle missing on angular google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular google maps module for my Angular application (5.x.x) every things working fine except for the point that satellite toggle button is not showing which is default feature of google maps API. I saw on google official documentation screen there's an option to disable satellite view but don't know how to implement it in angular google maps API.

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
        <agm-marker [latitude]="lat"
                    [longitude]="lng"
                    [iconUrl]="'assets/images/robot/rad-tower.gif'"></agm-marker>
        <agm-marker [latitude]="-34.397"
                    [longitude]="149.644"
                    [iconUrl]="'assets/images/robot/rad-tower.gif'"></agm-marker>
        <agm-marker [latitude]="-33.397"
                    [longitude]="149.644"
                    [iconUrl]="'assets/images/robot/rad-tower.gif'"></agm-marker>
        <agm-marker [latitude]="-33.397"
                    [longitude]="150.644"
                    [iconUrl]="'assets/images/robot/rad-tower.gif'"></agm-marker>
      </agm-map>
```

Whereas lat and lng are simple variable with values

Comment: What about showing us your code?

Comment: Please review updated question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add these attributes `[fullscreenControl]='true' [mapTypeControl]='true'` in `<agm-map>`

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"  [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom" 
       [fullscreenControl]='true' [mapTypeControl]='true' >
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Comment: And your code is badly formatted and a good part of it is missing.

Comment: There is a preview to see how your answer is rendered. Please check it before posting an answer. I have modified your answer to make it render correctly.

Comment: I had same issue and it worked for me. dont know what u missed.
dont find any change in logic from your edit

Answer (score 11):

If you want to add toggle button (Map and Satellite) like default map then you should have to put below code:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"  [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
<agm-map-type-control></agm-map-type-control>
<agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It looks like `[fullscreenControl]` and `[mapTypeControl]` inputs may have been deprecated.

Comment: @C.Trenholm you're absolutely right, I noticed this change only after the last update (which task I don't perform too often).

Comment: Yes, this is correct implementation but this doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using JavaScript.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {
                    lat: -33.86,
                    lng: 151.209
                },
                zoom: 13,
                minZoom: 3,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                gestureHandling: 'greedy'
            });
```